# Search Index partitioning warning

Tags: search, crawling

We had index drive running out of space and suddenly search stopped working in SharePoint. We increased our index drive space but i still see this

[image]
When we try to reset index and full crawl, the crawl logs shows errors and successfull count as 0.

We tried clearing config cache too but still the same problem

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the log? Try running the SRx Search Health Reports to determine if the index location is failing.

Comment: Resolved it after restarting the server, the green tick came up and then reset index and full crawl